# Firebase Realtime Database - Data from Code doesn't "reach" the database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, read-write

I'm working with Firebase's realtime database in order to make a recipe application in android studio. The code runs fine and nothing crashes, but every time it's supposed to send information to the database, it does not. I attempted to create a shell for it to put data into, and instead, I saw it erase it once it got past the part where it was supposed to send the data. I've done all the required imports, implementations and dependencies according to their documentation, as well as wrote the code according to it too, but it doesn't seem to work.

Firebase Realtime Database before I send data, plus rules screenshot:

[Firebase RD before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9ZtI.png)

[Firebase RD rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQk40.png)

After it runs the logic to send the data, I see it go red and disappear, like it was deleted, and nothing is left behind.

Here is my HomeScreen.java code:

```
package com.capteamfour.recipeappdatabase;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

final FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers = mDatabase.getReference("USERS");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    newUser(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(),
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());

    String username = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
    String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();

    TextView userWelcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userWelcome);
    FloatingActionButton addRecipe = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addRecipeButton);
    ImageButton userProfile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.userProfileButton);

    // Welcomes the current user
    userWelcome.setText("Welcome, " + username + "!");

    // Creates a listener for the "add recipe" button; takes user to recipe form activity
    addRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toRecipeForm = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, recipeForm.class);
            startActivity(toRecipeForm);
        }
    });

    // Creates a listener for the "user Profile Button" button; takes user to profile activity
    userProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ToProfile = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(ToProfile);
        }
    });

    }

public void newUser(String name, String email)
{
    userProfile user = new userProfile(name, email);

    System.out.println("This is what I need to send: " + mDatabaseUsers.setValue(user));
    mDatabaseUsers.setValue(user);
}
```

}

I declare a database instance and create a reference to the USERS path as global variables, and then made a function newUser(String name, String email) that creates an instance of a userProfile() class for me and is supposed to then send it to the database using the next line (the Sys.out was me trying to see what it was attempting to send if anything at all).

userProfile class code:

```
package com.capteamfour.recipeappdatabase;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class userProfile {

private String username;
private String email;
private List<Recipe> subRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

// Not yet implemented
private List<Recipe> favRecipes = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Recipe> savedRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

// A user profile will include their name, the recipes they've submitted, as well as recipes they've
// favorited or saved to their profile. Saved recipes are private to the user.

public userProfile() {
    // Default constructor for DataSnapshot.getValue(userProfile.class) calls
}

public userProfile(String usernameIn, String emailIn)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsername () {
    return this.username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

/*
    Each of these add functions will check the length of the given array and either
    add to the end of it if there's already results, or just adds it on the empty array.

    Example: array empty, then array[0] = recipe
             array has values, then array[length + 1] = recipe
 */

public void addSubRecipe (Recipe recipe) {
    int size = this.subRecipes.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        subRecipes.add(recipe);
    }
    else {
        subRecipes.add(size+1, recipe);
    }
}

public List<Recipe> getSubRecipes() {
    return subRecipes.subList(0, (subRecipes.size()));
}
/*
These are commented out to prevent additional bugs and confusion while they're not implemented

public void addSavedRecipe (Recipe recipe) {
    int size = this.savedRecipes.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        savedRecipes.add(recipe);
    }
    else {
        savedRecipes.add(size + 1, recipe);
    }
}


    public List<Recipe> getSavedRecipes() {
    return this.savedRecipes.subList(0, (subRecipes.size() + 1));
    }

/*public void addFavRecipe (Recipe recipe) {
    int size = this.favRecipes.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        favRecipes.add(recipe);
    }
    else {
        favRecipes.add(size + 1, recipe);
    }
}

public List<Recipe> getFavRecipes() {
    return this.favRecipes.subList(0, (subRecipes.size() + 1));
}*/
```

}

In this class, I made sure to have an empty constructor with additional constructors and the usual get/set functions so that the database could work with it.

I appreciate any and all pointers that anyone could provide on how to fix this issue. This is for my college capstone course, and it's holding us up quite drastically for what appears to be no good reason. Thanks everyone.

Comment: A possible cause of your problem may be calling setValue twice in a row. 

    `System.out.println("This is what I need to send: " + mDatabaseUsers.setValue(user));
    mDatabaseUsers.setValue(user);`

Print only the content of user instead. Do you see any log from firebase database in your AndroidStudio console?

Comment: "After it runs the logic to send the data, I see it go red and disappear, like it was deleted, and nothing is left behind." Do you see this in the Firebase console? If so, that typically means that there's a/another process that is immediately overwriting the change your code made. Check your code for a realtime listener that is writing in response to `onDataChange()`.

Comment: Is there any other place in your code where you are adding data to the database?